# SQL - Variable assignment with other columns selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the records as well as records count using common table expressions, but I want to store the records count in a variable and it will ofcourse give me the error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.

I am trying something like this

```
declare @count int

;with allRecords as 
(
   -- query fetching all the records with many joins
),
recordsCount as 
(
    select count(*) as Total from allRecords
)
select allRecords.*, @count=recordsCount.Total from allRecords, recordsCount 
where -- multiple conditions
```

Is there any work around for this?

Actually the `@count` variable is an `output` variable of my stored procedure so I want to return the result as well as fill this `@count` variable

Comment: why do you make select from allRecords, not just select @count=count(*) as Total from allRecords?

Comment: @xdd - Already tried, doesn't work! Gives syntax error. That is also not allowed. Tried other different variations also

Comment: try this
;with allRecords as 
(
   -- query fetching all the records with many joins
)
select @count = count(*) from allRecords

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. If you want to get the number of rows the select statement returned into a variable you should use the built-in global variable [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx):

```
DECLARE @count int

;WITH allRecords as 
(
   -- query fetching all the records with many joins
)

SELECT allRecords.*
FROM allRecords

SELECT @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
```

**Update:**

Well, in that case you have no choise that I'm aware of other then using a temporary table:

```
SELECT /* columns */ INTO #tempTableName 
-- rest of the select statement

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) 
FROM #tempTableName

SELECT * 
FROM #tempTableName 
WHERE <conditions>

DROP TABLE #tempTableName
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar! But actually I put few filters when I select records from `allRecords` and so `@@ROWCOUNT` will give me filtered rows count while I want the original rows count of `allRecords`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int

;with allRecords as 
(
   -- query fetching all the records with many joins
)
select @count = count(*) as Total from allRecords
```

Comment: But I want to select `allRecords.*` as well and that is the main problem

Comment: i asked you in comment. why do you want select, if your procedure returns count? or you want additional line with count?

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I want to get all the records as well as count of it. It is my business requirement

Comment: in outher words you want to make report? not just select. can you give exapmle of desired output?

Comment: Its not report! I am showing the data in the table and so I want to show the results as well as the total records that are there

Comment: this IS report - you show the data in pretty view. why dont you want make two selects? first retrieve lines, second - count? or the first - count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114817/discussion-between-xdd-and-pawan-nogariya).

Comment: Is your concepts clear about `common table expressions` in sql server? Because I am using that in my query. They are not two queries

Comment: when i say about two queryes i mean all your query with all cte. and i ask you to show us desired output - it will helps a lot. someone will make query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a temp table or table variable here. You can then do separate statements for `select @count = count(*) from #allrecords` and `select * from #allrecords`